# Any Issues with ScriptCalendar

Tags: javascript, seo, calendar

In looking for a javascript based events calendar (for displaying events on a calendar) and came across [ScriptCalendar](http://www.scriptcalendar.com/scrptcal/default2.aspx) which seems pretty good, but their SEO tactics seem to be somewhat suspect.  Download it and look at the scmrkt0912.htm file to see what I mean.

Has anyone used this Calendar, are there any comments on how good it is?

Comment: For what it's worth, there is no possible way short of catastrophic head injury that I'd ever pay for anything sold from a website that looks like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's awesome.  If you need an event calendar and you don't have server side scripting like ASP.NET or PHP it's perfect.  It's javascript and can be hosted on a plain html website.  (FYI:  There is code available on the website that allows you to use it ASP.NET or PHP).

It may not be the best looking website out there, but perhaps you need to do something other a cursory look at it.  The website allows to download a demo version of the calendar that has some limitations.  But, there is complete transparency with the demo.  It functions as the website describes.  You can see all functionality for yourself.

I recommend getting the demo if you are interested in an event calendar.

Comment: Thanks Neil, What about the obvious SEO tricks for other websites in the scmrkt0912.htm file?